# Showing InfoWindow (using InfoBubble) in street view

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently I have a map with some markers (loaded by a loop from an XML) and I am using a little plugin (InfoBubble) to improve the infowindows.
The problem is that in the normal map I can load, show and hide the infowindows clicking on the markers and it works as expected. But when I change to street view mode the infowindow is only shown the first time, if I close it, it never is shown again and I get an error from the infobubble plugin when it tries to get the current map:

> Uncaught TypeError: map.getDiv is not a function

Code when I load the street view (this works as expected, but maybe it can be improved):

```
// _this.Gmap.Map represents the current map
// _this.Gmap.Markers[index] represents the current marker
// _this.Gmap.InfoWindows[index] represents the current infowindow for the current marker with same index
// $('.Gmarker') is the html content inside the infowindow

google.maps.event.addListener(_this.Gmap.InfoWindows[index], 'domready', function () {
    var $target = $('.Gmarker').parent().parent();
    $target.addClass('InfoWindow');
    $target.next().addClass('InfoWindowArrow');

    // close the current infowindow
    $('.close', '.Gmarker').on('click', function () {
        _this.Gmap.InfoWindows[index].close();
    });

    // change to street view
    $('.streetview', '.Gmarker').on('click', function () {
        var $thismarker = $(this);
        var ll = [];
        for (var i in _this.Gmap.InfoWindows[index].position) {
            if (_this.Gmap.InfoWindows[index].position[i] !== undefined) ll.push(_this.Gmap.InfoWindows[index].position[i]);
        }
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(ll[0], ll[1]);
        var panorama = _this.Gmap.Map.getStreetView();
        _this.Gmap.StreetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(latlng, 100, function () {
            if (arguments[1] === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
                $('.buttons .streetview', $thismarker).hide();
                panorama.setPosition(latlng);
                panorama.setPov({
                    heading: !$('pov heading', $row).text().length ? parseFloat($('pov headcar', $row).text()) : parseFloat($('pov heading', $row).text()),
                    pitch: !$('pov pitch', $row).text().length ? parseFloat($('pov pitchar', $row).text()) : parseFloat($('pov pitch', $row).text()),
                    zoom: parseInt($('pov zoom', $row).text())
                });
                _this.Gmap.HideMarkers();

                // here is where I show the current (selected) marker with its infowindow. this works.
                _this.Gmap.Markers[index].setVisible(true);
                _this.Gmap.InfoWindows[index].open(_this.Gmap.Map.getStreetView());

                panorama.setVisible(true);
                google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'closeclick', function () {
                    $('.buttons .streetview', $thismarker).show();
                    _this.Gmap.HideMarkers(true);
                });
            }
            else {
                // there is no sv
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Code to show the infowindows through the markers. It does not work in street view mode:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(_this.Gmap.Markers[index], 'click', function () {
    _this.Gmap.HideInfoWindows();
    _this.Gmap.HideMarkers();
    _this.Gmap.Markers[index].setVisible(true);

    if (_this.Gmap.Map.getStreetView().getVisible()) {
        _this.Gmap.InfoWindows[index].open(_this.Gmap.Map.getStreetView()); // this line throws the error
    }
    else _this.Gmap.InfoWindows[index].open(_this.Gmap.Map);
    $('.mini', '#resultados').fadeOut(250);
    _this.Gmap.ReCenterMap();
});
```

What happens is that when I switch to the street view mode I can still see the infowindow but if I close it I can't reopen it anymore with the error that I commented above.

Comment: can you provide an example? I see the error too, but the error shouldn't prevent the InfoBubble from being displayed

Comment: I had the hope of someone could see any error directly in the code posted. Right now I am making some tests at jsfiddle with the api example code (using infowindow without the infobubble extension) and all works well. Making a working example could take some time and I am close to get out of work so If I can't solve it now I will make that example on Monday.

Comment: For a start check **inside** the `click`-handler of the markers if `index` is what you expect. You open "some" InfoBubble, but when it's not the correct InfoBubble, it will be placed outside of the viewport. Using `this` as 2nd argument for `_this.Gmap.InfoWindows[index].open` should always draw the the InfoBubble at the marker-position

Comment: The `index` is the same for both (marker and infowindow) and both have the same position. Currently, I am using the marker as second parameter for the infobubble (`_this.Gmap.InfoWindows[index].open(_this.Gmap.Map.getStreetView(), _this.Gmap.Markers[index]`) but I get the same error. What I saw is that the infowindow error is related to a Map method `.getDiv()`, but that method is not available throught `.getStreetView()`.

Comment: Debugging the InfoBubble plugin, I can see that it is not ready for Street View, because it always tries to get the `.getDiv()` method from the Map (not panorama), but the object returned throught `Map.getStreetView()` has not that method, it just has an object called `j` with the dom map element. Modifying the plugin I can show the infowindow properly, but It shows more errors related to the issue. Once I fix the plugin I will post an answer explaining it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InfoBubble plugin has no compatibility with the Street View object returned by `map.getStreetView()` method.

It throws an error because it's trying to get map methods `.getDiv()`, `.getCenter()` and `.panTo()`. To solve it, I fixed a little bit the plugin doing the following:

At lines when the plugin tries to use the methods that do not exists and throws the errors, for `.getDiv()`:

```
var mapDiv = typeof map.getDiv === "function" ? map.getDiv() : map.getContainer();
```

For `.getCenter()`:

```
var centerPos = projection.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(typeof map.getCenter === "function" ? map.getCenter() : map.position);
```

For `.panTo()`:

```
if (typeof map.getCenter === "function") {
    if (map.getCenter() != latLng) {
        map.panTo(latLng);
    }
}
```

Once fixed, we can successfully load the InfoBubbles for the street view map and the question code will work as it should.

Comment: the `j` is not stable, use `map.getStreetView().getContainer()` instead

Comment: I imagined it. In this case `map` represents the object returned by `.getStreetView()` so the correct would be `map.getContainer()`. Answer edited. Thank you very much for your help @Dr.Molle